# Treat TSLint warnings as errors in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

I would like to achieve the following:

- Show all TypeScript lint warnings as errors in the Error List.
- Have this set up by default for anyone who opens the project/solution.
- Break the build if there are lint errors, even if using standalone msbuild.exe.

Is this possible? So far I can only get warnings showing as errors by changing a personal setting in Web Essentials and they don't break the build.

Comment: Same need. But Visual Studio 2015 (Without Extensions!)